# pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers with NaN in multi index

Tags: pandas, multi-index

Consider the following dataframe

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame()
my_df.at[0,'tunnel1']=3
my_df.at[1,'tunnel1']=3
my_df.at[1,'tunnel2']=2
my_df.at[2,'tunnel1']=3
my_df.at[2,'tunnel2']=2
my_df.at[3,'tunnel1']=4
my_df.at[3,'tunnel2']=1
my_df.at[3,'tunnel3']=4
my_df.at[4,'tunnel1']=1
my_df.at[4,'tunnel2']=5
my_df.at[4,'tunnel3']=1
my_df.at[5,'tunnel1']=1
my_df.at[5,'tunnel2']=5
my_df.at[5,'tunnel3']=1
my_df.at[5,'tunnel4']=3
my_df.at[6,'tunnel1']=6
my_df.at[6,'tunnel2']=5
my_df.at[6,'tunnel3']=5
my_df.at[6,'tunnel4']=2
my_df['data1']='ham'
my_df['data2']='eggs'
my_df['data3']='coffee'
```

df looks like

```
   tunnel1  tunnel2  tunnel3  tunnel4 data1 data2   data3
0      3.0      NaN      NaN      NaN   ham  eggs  coffee
1      3.0      2.0      NaN      NaN   ham  eggs  coffee
2      3.0      2.0      NaN      NaN   ham  eggs  coffee
3      4.0      1.0      4.0      NaN   ham  eggs  coffee
4      1.0      5.0      1.0      NaN   ham  eggs  coffee
5      1.0      5.0      1.0      3.0   ham  eggs  coffee
6      6.0      5.0      5.0      2.0   ham  eggs  coffee
```

Then set a multiindex

```
my_df = my_df.set_index(['tunnel1', 'tunnel2', 'tunnel3', 'tunnel4'])
```

Looks like

```
                               data1 data2   data3
tunnel1 tunnel2 tunnel3 tunnel4                    
3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
        2.0     NaN     NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
                        NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
4.0     1.0     4.0     NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
1.0     5.0     1.0     NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
                        3.0       ham  eggs  coffee
6.0     5.0     5.0     2.0       ham  eggs  coffee
```

Now I want to slice it so that  get rows for each unique entry of the multiindex

```
for configuration in my_df.index.unique():
            mini_df=my_df.loc[configuration]
```

> pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers

First index slider is

```
configuration
(3.0, nan, nan, nan)
```

And this i believe is causing the error.

What I want from my loop is

mini_df

```
   tunnel1  tunnel2  tunnel3  tunnel4 data1 data2   data3
0      3.0      NaN      NaN      NaN   ham  eggs  coffee
```

mini_df'

```
   tunnel1  tunnel2  tunnel3  tunnel4 data1 data2   data3
1      3.0      2.0      NaN      NaN   ham  eggs  coffee
2      3.0      2.0      NaN      NaN   ham  eggs  coffee
```

mini_df''

```
   tunnel1  tunnel2  tunnel3  tunnel4 data1 data2   data3
3      4.0      1.0      4.0      NaN   ham  eggs  coffee
```

mini_df'''

```
   tunnel1  tunnel2  tunnel3  tunnel4 data1 data2   data3
4      1.0      5.0      1.0      NaN   ham  eggs  coffee
```

Any suggestions on what to try here please?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try `replace` or `fillna` the `NaN` with string 'NaN'

```
my_df = my_df.fillna('NaN').set_index(['tunnel1', 'tunnel2', 'tunnel3', 'tunnel4'])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately there's no way that I can have dummy data in the table.  The tool that reads it later needs it to be truly empty.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) + [`Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
for id1 in my_df.index.get_level_values(0).unique():
    print(my_df.xs(id1))
```

You couls save the dataframes in a dict:

```
df_id1={id1:my_df.xs(id1) for id1 in my_df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()}
for key in df_id1:
    print(f'df_id1[{key}]')
    print('-'*50)
    print(df_id1[key])

df_id1[3.0]
--------------------------------------------------
                        data1 data2   data3
tunnel2 tunnel3 tunnel4                    
NaN     NaN     NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
2.0     NaN     NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
                NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
df_id1[4.0]
--------------------------------------------------
                        data1 data2   data3
tunnel2 tunnel3 tunnel4                    
1.0     4.0     NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
df_id1[1.0]
--------------------------------------------------
                        data1 data2   data3
tunnel2 tunnel3 tunnel4                    
5.0     1.0     NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
                3.0       ham  eggs  coffee
df_id1[6.0]
--------------------------------------------------
                        data1 data2   data3
tunnel2 tunnel3 tunnel4                    
5.0     5.0     2.0       ham  eggs  coffee
```

---

We can also use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
for i, group in my_df.groupby(level=0):
#for i, group in my_df.groupby('tunnel1'): #latest versions of pandas
    print(group)

                                data1 data2   data3
tunnel1 tunnel2 tunnel3 tunnel4                    
1.0     5.0     1.0     NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
                        3.0       ham  eggs  coffee
                                data1 data2   data3
tunnel1 tunnel2 tunnel3 tunnel4                    
3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
        2.0     NaN     NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
                        NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
                                data1 data2   data3
tunnel1 tunnel2 tunnel3 tunnel4                    
4.0     1.0     4.0     NaN       ham  eggs  coffee
                                data1 data2   data3
tunnel1 tunnel2 tunnel3 tunnel4                    
6.0     5.0     5.0     2.0       ham  eggs  coffee
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, unfortunately I am not getting very unique value of the  multi index with this method.  You can see that df_id1[3.0] has tunnel2 values of nan and 2.0; and df_id1[1.0] has tunne4 values of nan and 3.0.